# How can i get rid of this pinching in my mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, topology

Huy guys, I am new to 3ds modeling and I started to model and I encounter this problem. I have tried to keep the quads but the pinching is still there.

Thank you for your answer.

[image: This is the main shape]

[image: The pinching is visible]

[image: Another try]

Comment: The problematic area is known as a "pole" - a vertex with more than 4 edges stemming from it.  These can be sometimes necessary in a mesh (particularly when defining edge flow), but can cause shading artifacts especially when placed. near an angled area that is shaded smooth. The best solution is to try and move the "pole" geometry onto more of a flat area. You can still keep it - just move it away from the edge.

Comment: maybe share this part of your object so that we try another topology? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thank you guys for everything, I don't know how to upload the model here so I will attach a transfer link, I hope I don't' break any rule. https://we.tl/t-omzgf2t5pk